# sport vs. exercise

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between: 'I don't do any sport' and 'I don't get any exercise'? If one does a morning workout and goes crosscoutry skiing, biking, swimming to keep fit and never takes part in competitions, can this person say about themselves: 'I don't do any sport'?

Comment: It no doubt varies considerably with local culture and customs, but generally "sport" implies some sort or organized activity -- tennis game (with opponent), bike ride with a group, etc.  Not necessarily competitive in the sense of keeping score, but often a situation where score might be kept.  "Exercise", on the other hand, is anything that involves a more intense activity than normal, especially if the purpose of the "exercise" is to provide that activity.

Comment: Thank you. My impresson is that 'sport' implies you are good enough at it as well. I used to play a bit of table tennis with novices like myself, and the score was actually kept but was it 'sport'? I don't think so - I never had a teacher and never practised my technique. So if anyone asks me if I do or did any sport, should my answer be 'No'? That seems  really tricky ...

Comment: Yes, "sport" probably implies a bit of skill or technique.  But I guess I'm having trouble understanding why this worries you.  You could reply, "Not really, but I sometimes knock around a ping-pong ball with the family."  Or some such.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in the details because I need to give feedback to my students when they ask me what actually counts as 'sport'.

Answer (score 1):

Sports can be entirely amateur, even if one is not very able.

A 40 year old beer drinker who is part of an amateur baseball or bowling league can validly say, "Oh, yes, I still play a little sports."

The main distinction is between a competitive activity, even if just playfully competitive, and physical activity done to maintain one's physical condition ("exercise").

However some competitions involves such minimal physical activity that they are more considered "games" than sport.  Billiards is an excellent example. Table tennis perfectly balances the boundary between a game (if playful) and a sport (if serious).

And then there is golf.  Is it a sport or a game? The debate will rage on endlessly.  In any case, it is also a wonderful way to get a full day of great exercise!

Comment: ...also a wonderful way to ruin a perfectly good walk.

Answer (score 0):

'Sport' is something you do for entertainment. You can fish for sport, which means you do it for fun rather than to put food on the table. And you may get no exercise.

You might lift weights for exercise. 'Sport' in that context might imply competition. If you do it alone, with the intention of building muscle, it's not sport.

Comment: I don't think that professional (American) football players are doing it for "entertainment".  But it's still a "sport".  And many folks are into the sport of running/jogging for the health benefits, not for the entertainment value.

Comment: The distinct isn't perfect. At the same time, people who watch football are doing so for entertainment. And while the players are getting exercise, the are not doing it*for* exercise. Sure, running is a sport, but when my doctor asks me if I'm getting exercise, and I bring up running, she has no idea if I'm training for a triathlon. My medal with my running time on it pertains to the sport, not the health benefits.